# Solving strange effects in audio waveforms

Tags: noise

I have generated two similar audio waves, but one of them is presenting some strange effects when played. I have attached both files:

[Original Audio](https://www.dropbox.com/s/sf96jrb445vsm13/raw.wav?dl=0)
[FilteredAudio](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ao4zj7cgaligmaq/raw.filter.wav?dl=0)

They are both PCM 16 bits little endian pure audio files, 8khz rate.

I would like to know:

1) Why is the second audio presenting hissing effects? The waveforms seem very similar to me.
2) What kind of filtering could I perform to attenuate these effects, and get a more comfortable audio?

Thanks.

Edit: I changed the file formats to windows WAV

Comment: I cant even open them...  but 8khz is very low for audio.

Comment: I can't open them either. Two questions, 1) what format are they in & 2) why are you working at 8kHz? Work at something more appropriate & hammer it down right at the very end, if you really really must. Any noise at 8k is likely to be aliasing - you can't filter it because there's no headroom to filter

Comment: The format was headerless raw audio, I edited the message and changed them to Windows WAV. There are bandwidth restrictions over the audio, that's why I am using a very low sampling rate.

Comment: I tried opening them in Adobe Audition as .raw - PCM raw data. I got nothing usable, just noise as if the file was not read properly. Seems like nobody here knows the answer, so I'm wondering if another SE might be better for this. I'll flag it and one of the mods can decide. I'm wondering if this is more of a programming issue as you are working with raw audio - that is pretty unusual for sound designers.

Comment: I'm not really sure SO would have any better idea what to do since they aren't used to analyzing sound for what is actually happening.  We don't have a lot of experience here, but there are a few DSP guys that come through occasionally.  One of them might have an idea on this.  I think that's probably the best chance for a solution to this, so I'll leave it here for now.